# Redefining __init__ with metaclass in Python 3

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm learning meta programming in python 3. My professor did give us this exercise:

*Write the metaclass Spell that transforms the instances of Student in a Wizard.*

I did this:

```
class Spell(type):
    def __new__(cls, classname, supers, cls_dict):
        cls_dict['__init__'] = Spell.toWizard()
        cls_dict['__qualname__'] = 'wizard'
        return type.__new__(cls, 'wizard', supers, cls_dict)

    @staticmethod
    def toWizard():
        def init(*args):
            wizard(args, 'fire_spell')
        return init    

class student(metaclass=Spell):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class person():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

class wizard(person):
    def __init__(self, name, magic):
        self.magic = magic
        super().__init__(name)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = student('name1')
    print(s.__dict__)
    s = student('name2')
    print(s.__dict__)
```

The wizard class `__init__` is correctly being called instead of student class `__init__`, however the objects created have an empty `__dict__`. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `init()` replacement function creates a *local* `wizard()` instance, and doesn't return anything:

```
def init(*args):
    wizard(args, 'fire_spell')
```

That's a separate instance, `self` is not touched.

Don't use `__new__`; that produces a new class. You only renamed the `student` class and gave it an ineffectual `__init__` method.

Override the `__call__` method to hook into creating the *instances*. There you can replace or ignore the first argument, which is the `student` class object and use the `wizard` class in its place:

```
class Spell(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # ignore the cls argument, return a wizard instead
        if 'magic' not in kwargs and len(args) < 2:
            # provide a default magic value
            kwargs['magic'] = 'fire_spell'
        return wizard(*args, **kwargs)
```

Because `student` only takes a single argument normally, so the above adds a `magic` argument if none is specified.

Demo:

```
>>> student('name1')
<__main__.wizard object at 0x10f1e8198>
>>> vars(_)
{'magic': 'fire_spell', 'name': 'name1'}
```

Comment: @Aran-Fey: sorry for the delay there, I had to attend to something else for a bit.